# Remove message from MessageBag

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, session-variables

How can I remove an error message from a `MessageBag`?

I've been trying to remove a specific element from the message array that `MessageBag` uses without any luck.

I'm getting the same error message twice.

```
@if($errors->has('undefined'))
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <h4>Failure.</h4>
        {{ $errors->first('undefined') }}
    </div>
    <?
        // $messages = $errors->getMessages();
        $messages = $errors->toArray();
        unset($messages['undefined']);
    ?>
@endif

@if($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-error">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <h4>Error!</h4>
        {{ $errors->first() }}
    </div>
@endif
```

#### Edit

I have done something like this and it seems to work.

```
<?
    $messages = $errors->toArray();
?>

        @if(array_key_exists('undefined', $messages))
            <?
                $message_array = $messages['undefined'];
                $message = $message_array[0];
                unset($messages['undefined']);
            ?>

            <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            <h4>Failure.</h4>
                {{ $message }}
            </div>
        @endif

        <?
            foreach ($messages as $error => $error_array) { 
        ?>
            <div class="alert alert-error">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            <h4>Error!</h4>
                {{ $error_array[0] }}
            </div>
         <?
            }
         ?>
```

But my question still remains?  Why is this happening in first place? 
Does it has to do with the **Session**? I know that the `errors` variable it is stored in the Session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.MessageBag.html

Unfortunately, Laravel does not offer methods for removing errors from the MessageBag instance.  What you can do is make the 'undefined' error a variable so it's not even in the MessageBag to begin with and just use similar logic to show/hide that.

```
return View::make('test.view')
        ->with('undefined', 'Something is undefined')
        ->withInput($input)->withErrors($validator);
```

Passing by reference example.  You could potentially modify the `MessageBag` class to have it pass by reference but it would be hacky.

```
<?php
class foo 
{
    public $value = 42;

    public function &getValue() 
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}

$obj = new foo;
$myValue = &$obj->getValue(); // $myValue is a reference to $obj->value, which is 42.
$myValue = 2;

echo $obj->getValue(); // prints the new value of $obj->value, i.e. 2.
?>
```

Notice the `&` prepended to both the function name and the call.

Comment: The code sample was just an example,I know I can overcome this by passing it to the view in a different way,my main point is *how to remove a message from the `MessageBag`*,and why this isn't possible since they are stored in an array. Thnx for the answer!

Comment: The messages are in an array within the `MessageBag` class, but unfortunately, it's `protected`.  So I guess the true answer to your question would be to create a new class which extends `MessageBag` and include methods for directly managing the `$messages` array.  Here's a good tutorial on extending classes in Laravel 4.  http://fideloper.com/extend-request-response-laravel

Comment: You can access the `$messages` array via the methods that the class provide to you. You can see both functions in my example. So I don't think it's the true answer to my question.

Comment: You can't access it.  You are just making a copy of it and storing it.  Making changes (unsetting) to the copy isn't going to change the original variable.  That's why your second way works, because you are only using the copy.

Comment: Why are you saying that? Are you sure about it? I just saw the source file of `MessageBag` and it returns a reference to the `messages` array.

Comment: I'm looking at the source as well, specifically for the `toArray()` function which calls the `getMessages()` function which returns the array of messages, but not by reference.  http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Support.MessageBag.html#245-253

Comment: By what then? Unless I'm missing something big, what you are saying doesn't make sense. It return a reference to `messages` array `return $this->messages;`. Why are you thinking it returns a copy;

Comment: It's not returning a reference because it's not passing it by reference.  It's just creating a copy of the original variable.  Maybe this will help you understand at what must be done to pass by reference.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php  I've also updated the answer with a better example tailored to this specific scenario.

Comment: OK, that was very revealing! Coming from `Java` I didn't know that *array* is treated this way in `PHP`!! You can see here why. ideone.com/aVIC0d Thnx for insisting. Although your answer was not very informative your comments were! +1 I'll consider to accept your answer I think you deserve it!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, knowing that I can re-create the `MessageBag` and also access the errors of the current `MessageBag` with `->getMessages()`. All I did was:

```
$validationErrors = $validator->errors()->getMessages();
unset($validationErrors['email']);
unset($validationErrors['phone_number']);

$newValidationErrors = new MessageBag($validationErrors);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Is it possible to assign the new MessageBag to the original validator? `$validator`

Answer (score 2):

I opened a [PR](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/46043) for this and it was merged. As of Laravel 10, a `forget` method was added to the `MessageBag` and you can do:

```php
$validationErrors = $validator->errors();
$validationErrors->forget('key');
```