# Laravel 8 remove error message from validator errorMessageBag

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-8, laravel-validation

I am using laravel 8. I need to validate 3 fields to make 1 phone number. The flow is to combine the 3 fields and then save to database. Validation is triggered when one of the fields is not the correct format ( typed in char, more than 4 digits, etc ). The validation error message should only be for the first field. Meaning I need to delete the 2nd and 3rd fields' error message and just update/create the error message on the first field.

Validation itself is done but I cannot delete the error message when returning to the frontend. If possible, I dont want to update the front end code for this since this is a laravel logic.

This is my version of the failedValidation method:

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    $errorMessages = $validator->errors();
    $messages = $errorMessages->getMessages();
    if ($errorMessages->has('phNo_1') || $errorMessages->has('phNo_2') || $errorMessages->has('phNo_3')) {
        $errorMessages->add('phNo_1', $errorMessages->first('phNo_1'));
        unset($messages['phNo_2']);
        unset($messages['phNo_3']);
    }
    parent::failedValidation($validator);
}
```

The code is based in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56505039) answer. When I log the `$messages`, I can see that the `phNo_2` and `phNo_3`'s message is already deleted but I am unable to assign it back to `$validator`.

I am aware of the `forget` method of `$validator->errors()` but the method is for laravel 10.

Additional Code:

ValidPhoneNumber.php

```
public function __construct($input)
{
    $this->input = $input;
}

/**
 * Determine if the validation rule passes.
 *
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return bool
 */
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $ph_01 = $this->input['phNo_1'];
    $ph_02 = $this->input['phNo_2'];
    $ph_03 = $this->input['phNo_3'];

    // Check if all fields are required or null
    if (empty($ph_01) && empty($ph_02) && empty($ph_03)) {
        return true;
    }

    // Check if all fields are integers and have max 4 digits
    if (is_numeric($ph_01) && is_numeric($ph_02) && is_numeric($ph_03)) {
        if (strlen($ph_01) <= 4 && strlen($ph_02) <= 4 && strlen($ph_03) <= 4) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Get the validation error message.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function message()
{
    return 'The validation error message.';
}
```

FormRequest:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ...
        'phNo_1' => ['nullable', 'required_with:phNo_2,phNo_3', new ValidPhoneNumber($this->input())],
        'phNo_2' => ['nullable', 'required_with:phNo_1,phNo_3', new ValidPhoneNumber($this->input())],
        'phNo_3' => ['nullable', 'required_with:phNo_1,phNo_2', new ValidPhoneNumber($this->input())],
        ...
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

For FormRequest:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'phNo_1' => ['nullable', 'required_with:phNo_2,phNo_3', new ValidPhoneNumber($this->input())],
        'phNo_2' => ['nullable', 'required_with:phNo_1,phNo_3'],
        'phNo_3' => ['nullable', 'required_with:phNo_1,phNo_2'],
    ];
}

public function attributes(): array
{
    return [
        'phNo_1' => 'Phone Number',
    ];
}


public function messages(): array
{
    return [
        'phNo_1.required_with' => ':attribute Format is wrong',
    ];
}
```

Just assign the Custom Rule to one of the fields. But correctly add `required_with`  validation to all fields.

With this code, all 3 fields are connected with required_with and other conditions will be inside ValidPhoneNumber